# wait, notify, synchronized Java

Tags: java, многопоточность

Нужна помощь в задаче:
Нужно, чтобы поток `Write` увеличивал значение числа на 1 и после каждого увеличения блокировался, а поток `Reader` выводил данное значение и блокировался, поток `Control` каждую секунду вызывал `notifyAll()`, и работа программы продолжалась до десяти.
Проблема такова, что почему-то поток `Reader` выводит числа по 2 раза (1,1,3,3 и т.д.).
И ещё подскажите, как в `notifyAll()` поставить таймер, чтобы он вызывался каждую секунду.

**Main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Resource resource = new Resource();
    Write write = new Write(resource);
    Reader reader = new Reader(resource);
    write.start();
    reader.start();
    while (!resource.end) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            synchronized (resource) {
                resource.notifyAll();
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

**Write:**

```
public class Write extends Thread {
    Resource rs;

    public Write(Resource rs) {
        this.rs = rs;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (rs) {
            //System.out.println("Write start");
            while (!rs.end) {
                rs.num++;
                System.out.println("Write: " + rs.num);
                try {
                    rs.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
                if (rs.num >= 10) {
                    rs.end = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Reader:**

```
public class Reader extends Thread {
    Resource rs;

    public Reader(Resource rs) {
        this.rs = rs;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (rs) {
            System.out.println("Reader Start");
            while (!rs.end) {
                System.out.println("Reader : " + rs.num);
                try {
                    rs.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Resourse:**

```
public class Resource {
    int num;
    boolean end;
}
```

Comment: Лучше бы подсказали чем орфографию проверяли бы.....

Comment: Качество оформления вопроса сильно влияет на шанс получить ответ. Так что стоит сказать спасибо 0xdb.

Comment: День добрый. Не следует кардинально менять вопрос, особенно, если на него уже дан ответ.

Comment: Ответ на дополнительный вопрос уже есть в ответе Serodv: `Thread.sleep(1000);`.

Answer (score 4):

Основная проблема в приведённом вами варианте решения задачи - полное отсутствие синхронизации между потоками. Отсюда и следствие - reader может несколько раз прочитать одно и то же значение, writer - записать без ожидания чтения. Обычно алгоритм синхронизации между потоками выглядит следующим образом: поток выполняет цикл пока не будет прерван либо не выполнится некое условие (в вашем случае rs.end), внутри цикла происходит блокировка общего ресурса и сразу осуществляется проверка, разрешает ли логика приложения воспользоваться потоку этим ресурсом. Для этого, например, можно ввести boolean переменные, которые определяют, какому потоков на данный момент разрешено использовать ресурс. Примерно так я вижу решение вашей задачи:

```
class Resource {
    int num;
    boolean end, isRead, isWrite, isControl;
}
```

Reader

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (!rs.end) {
        synchronized (rs) {
            while (!rs.isRead) {
                try {
                    rs.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Reader : " + rs.num);
            rs.isControl = true;
            rs.isRead = false;
            rs.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Writer

```
@Override
public void run() {
    while (!rs.end) {
        synchronized (rs) {
            while (!rs.isWrite) {
                try {
                    rs.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            rs.num++;
            System.out.println("Write: " + rs.num);
            if (rs.num >= 10) {
                rs.end = true;
            }
            rs.isWrite = false;
            rs.isRead = true;
            rs.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Control

```
 resource.isControl =  true;
 new Thread(() -> {
     while (!resource.end) {
         synchronized (resource) {
         while (!resource.isControl) {
             try {
                 resource.wait();
             } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
         resource.isControl = false;
         resource.isWrite = true;
         try {
             Thread.sleep(1000);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         resource.isControl = false;
         resource.isWrite = true;
         resource.notifyAll();
     }
   }
}).start();
```

Comment: ого, ваше ТЗ начинает обрастать подробностями